# addEventListener not working more then one time

Tags: javascript, express, dom

addEventListener only working for `scroll` and not working for `addMoreFields` and `removeFields`, if I put scroll section down then it works for `addMoreFields` and `removeFields` but not working for `scroll` now.

```
const wraping = document.querySelector('#Wraping');
const addMoreFields = document.querySelector('#btn-add');
const removeFields = document.querySelector('#btn-remove');
let inpName = 0;
const scroll = document.querySelector(".scrollToTop");

scroll.addEventListener("click", function(){
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
});


addMoreFields.addEventListener("click", function(){
  let input_tags = wraping.getElementsByTagName('input');
  if (input_tags.length < 10){
    inpName = inpName + 1;
    let newField = document.createElement('input');
    newField.setAttribute('type','text');
    newField.setAttribute('name','products[' + inpName + ']');
    newField.setAttribute('class','spacing form-control');
    newField.setAttribute('placeholder','Enter product URL_' + (inpName + 1));
    wraping.appendChild(newField);
  }
});

removeFields.addEventListener("click", function(){
  let input_tags = wraping.getElementsByTagName('input');
  if(input_tags.length > 1){
    wraping.removeChild(input_tags[(input_tags.length - 1)])
    inpName = inpName - 1;
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="mb-3">
   <label class="form-label">Monetization</label>
   <div id="Wraping">
     <input class="spacing form-control" placeholder="Past product URL" type="text" name="products[]">
   </div>
   <button id="btn-add" class="c-button compose-btn btn " type="button" name="add">Add</button>
   <button id="btn-remove" class="c-button compose-btn btn " type="button" name="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your html to reproduce this issue ?

Comment: okay, I'll provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

addEventListener takes a function reference as its second parameter. Here, you're directly calling the function when you try to add it. This should work for you:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
alert("document loaded!");
sliderRed.addEventListener("change", function(){alert(sliderRed.value)} );
// wrapped in a function
```

} );

Comment: can you explain this?

Comment: The code you provide is worked for me, but I still don't understand it can you please explain it more clearly.